# Python Flask Search MySQL database turns up ()

Tags: python, mysql, database, search, flask

I have been working on a Python Flask app for some time now. I have got it to connect to a mysql database and do a search but all it throws up is ().

I am not sure if it is not finding anything or there is an error, but the Database has one item in it.

This is the main .py file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect, flash
from connect_script import connection

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def homepage():
    flash("Hello")
    return render_template("main.html")


@app.route('/hello/', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    error = ""
    rows = None
    user_input = None
    data = None
    try:
        c, conn = connection()
        if request.method == "POST":
            data = c.execute("SELECT * FROM titles WHERE name='%s' ", (request.form["search"],))
            user_input = (request.form["search"],)
            return render_template("main.html", data=data, user_input=user_input)

    except Exception as e:
        error = (str(e))
        return render_template("main.html", error=error, user_input=user_input)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This file searches the Database and just pulls up results.html, and that looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html land="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Movie App</title>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/style.css') }}" />
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.ico') }}">
</head>
<body>
    {{ rows }}
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>

</html>
```

where {{ rows }} is all it renders is () nothing else. I have been searching around the net trying to find an answer but so far nothing.

The form that is is using looks like this

```
  <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" action="{{ url_for('hello') }}" method="POST" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search" value="{{ request.form.search }}">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Thanks for any help with this!

Comment: Sorry that took so long, I think this is what is in rows <bound method Cursor.executemany of <MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor object at 0x7f8390056990>>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few more hours I finally did it. I am not 100% on what was wrong.

But my final code is

```
@app.route('/hello/', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    error = ""
    rows = None
    user_input = None
    data = None
    try:
        c, conn = connection()
        if request.method == "POST":
            c.execute("SELECT * FROM titles WHERE name = %s ", (request.form["search"],))
            data = c.fetchall()
            user_input = (request.form["search"],)
            return render_template("results.html", data=data, user_input=user_input)

    except Exception as e:
        error = (str(e))
        return render_template("main.html", error=error, user_input=user_input)
```

So I believe this to be doing and where I went wrong is, after Flask connects to the Database and a user has sent out a search request. MySQL executes the line "`SELECT * FROM titles WHERE name = %s`" So this line selects ALL rows from the table `title`, using the `request.form["search"]` to replace `%s` with what the user searched for. What I did not know is that c.execute needed a list or a tuple I think as its second arg. Using the () around request and , turns into thus.

Finally, I then store the data into the arg data and fetchall, then output that to the HTML using `{{data}}` and a for loop.

Thank you very much too bakkal for helping me get to the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You'll at least want to iterate through the cursor

```
<ol>
    {% for row in rows %}
        <li> row data: {{ row }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Even so it's not going to be very presentable as in each iteration you'll be getting a tuple `(value_1, value_2, ...)`

You may want to use a `MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor` as dictionaries may be easier to work with in the flask template, then you can use e.g. `{{row.column_1}}` which is more readable than `{{row[0]}}` for the tuples version.

**If you still get nothing**

You can try display the count of the rows that matched the search, in the template:

```
Row count: {{rows.row_count}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the results page now turns out nothing. I have added this to the python script                                                               'c, conn = connection()
            cursor = c.cursor(dictionary=True)
            cursor.executemany('''SELECT * FROM titles WHERE name = %s''', request.form['search'])
            cursor.executemany = rows
            return render_template("results.html", rows=rows)' and used your {% for row in rows %} {{ row }} {% endfor %} I am not sure I am using the Dict of the MySQL right Sorry if this is hard to read

Comment: Still nothing, so the search is not coming up with anything. I am pretty sure I have the connection correct, I will try a few other ways to connect to make sure, it is pulling the connection from another script.

Comment: Sorry took so long I was making a silly mistake, So I used                    count = cursor.execute('''SELECT COUNT(*) FROM titles WHERE name''')[0]; and {{ count }} in the html but it still outputs nothing. [link](http://178.62.126.188/) is the link to the site, not sure how helpful that is though

Comment: So after working away with it, it now just says None, so I am guessing it is not finding anything in the Database?